# enable core dump logging with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, coredump

There is a core dump file and I can use gdb to open and check the call stack. And I can export the content to gdb.txt by typing `set logging on` inside the gdb app. Now I'd like to use a script to realize it, bash or python whatever. Is it doable?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You want to check out `gdb --help` particular the `--command` and/or  the `--eval--command` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -z "$1" ] && { echo executable required; exit 1; }
[ -z "$2" ] && { echo core required; exit 1; }
gdb --ex bt -ex quit "$1" "$2"
```

You can do `set logging on` if you want, or use the stdout from this script (possible filtered).